# Is "Let's Encrypt" good to use for securing SSL in mobile app?

Tags: android, ssl, mobile

I found Let's Encrypt compatibility from https://hackaday.com/2020/12/01/lets-encrypt-will-stop-working-for-older-android-devices/

It is quite worrying that some Android devices not compatible to use SSL cert issued by Let's encrypt.

What do you think ? Do you use their cert in your mobile app to secure SSL connection ?

I haven't tried their SSL cert. Just want to find out from others

Comment: FWIW, this was mainly a problem with Android's Private DNS implementation since browsers can just update their root. LetsEncrypt later add a cross-signing https://letsencrypt.org/2020/09/17/new-root-and-intermediates.html and is in the transition to the new chain https://letsencrypt.org/2023/07/10/cross-sign-expiration.html, with less than 5 percent of Android are to be affected https://www.composables.com/tools/distribution-chart (7.0 Nougat and before). Also, you're securing your *server* API endpoint, your app isn't actually affected, you can even just pin your cert there for older Android

Comment: Hence to use it for securing https API endpoint in android, better off to pin the cert right ?

Comment: If you can pin, yes. See https://approov.io/tools/static-pinning/, also, on https://doh.sigman.io/ the majority of public DoH servers out there also use LetsEncrypt, though not always, most of the time they use the same cert for DoT (Private DNS) which indicate it also works without pinning.